# OrderBy is not working

Tags: c#, linq, morelinq

I am trying the following code:

```
public IList<Brand> GetMobileDeviceBrands()
{
     var dataContext = dataContextFactory.CreateContext();

     var brands = (from b in dataContext.Brands
                   join d in dataContext.Devices on b.ID equals d.BrandID
                   where d.DeviceTypeID != 1
                   select b).OrderBy(b => b.Name).Distinct().ToList();

     return brands;         // not ordered by Name here
}
```

But not getting the ordered result as expected.

If I write `orderBy` in the controller as:

```
var Brands = devicesListService.GetMobileDeviceBrands().OrderBy(b => b.Name).ToList();
```

Its doing well. I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: Try switching the Distinct() and OrderBy..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distinct operator does not guarantee to keep the order of the values intact, so you need to swap the orderby and distinct operators:

```
var brands = (from b in dataContext.Brands
                   join d in dataContext.Devices on b.ID equals d.BrandID
                   where d.DeviceTypeID != 1
                   select b).Distinct().OrderBy(b => b.Name).ToList();
```